# Compiler doesn't free memory after exiting a block?

Tags: c, stack

I was reading about how stack and heap work when i got to know that when we make a block in c, the variables inside it have local scope but once the block is exit the stack pointer is not readjusted.
So I wrote a simple program to test this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int integer;
    integer = 10;
    {
        int integer2;
        integer2 = 20;
        printf("the address of integer2 is %x\n", &integer2);
    }
    int* integer2;
    printf("enter the memory address of integer2\n");
    scanf("%x", &integer2);
    int integer3;
    integer3 = 40;
    printf("%d %d", integer, *integer2);
    return 0;
}
```

And when i run the program and put the memory address of a variable inside the block into a pointer and then dereference it, it gets the exact value, isn't this the same as a memory leak? because there is no way to access the variable from it's name and most probably that variable wont be used again.

Comment: Stack allocation and deallocation happens on functions not blocks.

Comment: @Eraklon: That depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This does not indicate a memory leak.

A memory leak is allocated memory that is no longer reachable.

- You have not demonstrated that the memory is still allocated. You could get the same result from accessing memory that isn't allocated.
- You have not demonstrated that the memory is no longer reachable. You could get the same result from accessing memory that is still reachable.

In reality, the memory is probably still allocated, but it's also still reachable. Once the function exits, the memory will be freed automatically. No leak. You can verify this by calling the function a million times. The programs memory usage will not increase.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Here's why:

Either it is legal and well-defined to access that address or it isn't.

If it's legal and well-defined to access that address, then you can't have demonstrated a leak or error by accessing it unless you can get a result you can prove is wrong. You haven't done that.

If it's not legal and well-defined to access that address, then accessing that address is undefined behavior. Even if you did demonstrate a leak, all you demonstrated is that undefined behavior can cause a leak, which shouldn't surprise anyone.

Answer (score 1):

”The *lifetime* of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it” (C 2018 6.2.4 2).

The lifetime of `integer2` starts when program control enters the innermost block containing it (the opening `{` just before its definition) and ends when execution of that block ends. At the end of the lifetime, what ceases to exist is the **reservation** of memory.

The memory does not go away<sup>1</sup>. Just the guarantee that you can use it goes away. You can still try; the C standard does not prevent you, and compilers mostly do not stop you. But, once that memory is not reserved for `integer2`, some other code in the program might be using for something else, and you might break the program when you try to use it for `integer2`.

In other words, as long as the memory is reserved for use for `integer2`, the compiler has arranged for your program to work correctly in that regard. Storing values in `integer2` and loading them back will work. Once the memory is no longer reserved, the compiler has not arranged for your program to work correctly if you continue to use `integer2`.

It is not a memory leak because the program is still tracking what memory is reserved for use and what memory is not. It knows where the stack pointer is and where it needs to be when the function returns, and it manages that correctly. If you write:

```
{
    int integer2;
    integer2 = 20;
    printf("the address of integer2 is %p\n", (void *) &integer2);
}
{
    int integer4;
    integer4 = 40;
    printf("the address of integer4 is %p\n", (void *) &integer4);
}
```

then the compiler might use the same memory for `integer2` and `integer4`, because, once the memory is no longer reserved for `integer2`, the compiler may reuse it for `integer4`. If you get the same address when you run this, it shows the lifetime of `integer2` did indeed end, and the compiler is tracking memory and reusing it for other purposes, so it is not leaking.

(Incidentally, do not print address with `%x`. Cast the address to `void *` and print it with `%p`.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Usually. It is possible for the operating system to take memory away, but that generally does not happen in these situations.